# Is dependency injection container a singleton?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am learning DI in .Net Core and I find all examples only use one instance of `ServiceCollection`. I wonder whether this instance must be a singleton but I get confused because we can invoke `new`. Probably because of my lack of knowledge, it really makes sense to have multiple instances of `ServiceCollection`. Any comment and suggestion are welcome!

Comment: Dependency injection doesn't stop you from doing stupid things, it just tries to help you fall into the pit of success. While you can new-up anything you want, you simply just shouldn't be doing that. As for having 2 `ServiceCollection`s, I'm not sure what you mean by that. Why have you got that?

Comment: In some cases you can have multiple containers. The "outer" container is used to bootstrap the system with configuration and services that are then used to build an "inner" container which then becomes the "singleton" container used by the system. Note that the two containers are not used together - the first is used to configure the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's both more `efficient` and less `Dangerous` than creating multiple service providers. Creating one instance allows you to have all your services in one place instead of divided over multiple provider instances.

A service provider doesn't have to be a singleton, but it makes users of dependency injection frameworks less likely go down the **bad road**.

The **bad road** in this case is separating your `dependencies` and later having to pass/ know the right `dependency provider` to choose from when getting your dependencies.

This makes your code more complicated than it has to be, as well as creating no benefit for both you and especially other people who will join you on your project and have to figure out which provider had the object which can access the database.

Most `frameworks` have their `service providers` accessible statically which also allows you to retrieve services and merge the service provider into your project far easier. Having multiple instances would make this difficult.

Normally with dependency injection you would for example pass it directly in your constructor.

So in short:

1. It's convenient
2. efficient
3. easy to read and understand
4. makes it difficult to use it the wrong way
5. Allows it to be easily used as a static object